# Parsing a CSV file into HashMap stores a null value

Tags: java, csv, hashmap, bufferedreader

I am trying to read off a csv file and store the data into a hash map.
I am able to correctly add the key but when adding the value, it is adding null for every single one. I am not sure why. Here is my code:

EDITED CODE:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class ExampleActivity {
    public static HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public static void readCountry() throws IOException{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("countries.csv"));    
        String line;
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String str[] = line.split(",");
            if (str.length > 1) {
                System.out.println("Data 0: " + str[0]);
                System.out.println("Data 1: " + str[1]);
                hm.put(str[0].trim(), str[1]);
            }

        }
        //System.out.println(hm);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        readCountry();

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String l = null;

        System.out.println("Please enter a three letter country:");
        l = in.nextLine();
        l = l.trim();
        // System.out.println("Country Code: " + l + "\nCountry Name: " +
        // hm.get(l) );
        if (hm.containsKey(l)) {
            System.out.println("Country Code: " + l + "\nCountry Name: "
                + hm.get(l));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Missing key for " + l);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a sample of the CSV file

```
AFG,Afghanistan
AGO,Angola
AIA,Anguilla
...
```

Here is a screenshot of the output:
[image]

Comment: Why are you splitting your input string twice? Once outside the loop and once inside the loop. I'm not sure what you're attempting to do inside the for loop

Comment: share sample of csv file

Comment: I will edit the post, I originally used it once.

Comment: Your for loop in it's current structure won't help, one second

Comment: Did you comment out the HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>(); like @DarkKnight said?

Comment: Yes, I removed it completely.

Comment: Is it working now or did you discover the issue?

Comment: The issue was the CSV file. There was some weird invisible spacing in the words(even though it appeared normal). I really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: Even you have already accepted one answer. Maybe you are anyway interested to see an other solution. Have a look to my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
    String str[] = line.split(",");
    if (str.size() > 1){
        System.out.println("Data 0: " + str[0]);
        System.out.println("Data 1: " + str[1]);
        hm.put(str[0], str[1]);
    }
}
```

Your for loop is unecessary

Also look at Dark Knight's answer for your null values issue

EDIT

Can you add this to your code and see what it does:

```
if (hm.containsKey(l)
    System.out.println("Country Code: " + l + "\nCountry Name: " + hm.get(l) );
else
    System.out.println("Missing key for " + l);
System.out.println("Printing hashmap");
for(Entry<String, String> entry : hm.entrySet()) {
{
    System.out.println(entry.getKey());
    System.out.println(entry.getValue());   
}
```

EDIT2

```
hm.put(str[0].trim(), str[1]);
```

And the next bit

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String l;
System.out.println("Please enter a three letter country:");
l = in.nextLine();
l = l.trim();
```

Comment: Without the for loop, I'm getting an out of bounds error.

Comment: Check the update, sounds like your CSV file has lines with no comma in

Comment: There was some error with the csv file. I fixed that issue but the original issue (where value is null) is still happening. I also did what Dark Knight advised.

Comment: Ok, what's being printed out here:
System.out.println("Data 0: " + str[0]);
System.out.println("Data 1: " + str[1]);

Can you post example outputs from your code please?

@DarkKnight, any further suggestion for them?

Comment: It is displaying "Missing key for...". I guess its not being added correctly to the hash map.

Comment: Check the new bit, there's two possibilities, either it's not being added or it doesn't consider your new String of ZWE and the key to be equivalent

Comment: When printing the hashmap, it does show the correct key and correct value, So i guess it is the l that is not being considered equivalent.

Comment: OK, sounds like you need to trim some whitespace of. Look at the edit I'm about to do

Comment: This is very strange, it is still not working. Ill update my code, so you can see how i have it. by the way, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Comment out method local declaration of hashmap and it should work fine. Make change to code as below:

```
public static void readCountry() throws IOException{

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("d:/countries1.csv")); 
    String line;
  //  HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>(); Remove this line
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Stream API you could start with following snippet.

```
Path path = Paths.get("countries.txt");
Map<String, String> countries = Files.lines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        .filter((String l) -> !l.isEmpty())
        .map((Object t) -> ((String) t).split(",", 2))
        .collect(toMap((String[] l) -> l[0], 
                (String[] l) -> l.length > 1 ? l[1] : ""));
System.out.println("countries = " + countries);
```

output

```
countries = {AFG=Afghanistan, AIA=Anguilla, AGO=Angola}
```

The snippet filter out empty lines and for lines without a `,` the value is assigned as an empty string.

**edit** Your amended `readCountry` would look like

```
public static void readCountry() throws IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get("countries.txt");
    Map<String, String> hm = Files.lines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            .filter((String l) -> !l.isEmpty() && l.contains(","))
            .map((Object t) -> ((String) t).split(",", 2))
            .peek((String[] l) -> 
                 System.out.printf("Data 0: %s%nData 1: %s%n", l[0], l[1]))
            .collect(toMap((String[] l) -> l[0],
                    (String[] l) -> l[1]));
}
```

it store the key-value pairs in `hm` and produce as output

```
Data 0: AFG
Data 1: Afghanistan
Data 0: AGO
Data 1: Angola
Data 0: AIA
Data 1: Anguilla
```